# How do you add RefocusIt to Gimp?

Tags: plugins, gimp, compile, c++, c

I'm trying to compile Gimp with a special plugin called [Refocus-It](http://refocus-it.sourceforge.net/).  I know that I need to compile something.  Can somebody please explain what needs to be done?

I would like to accomplish this using the Code::Blocks, but I think it's for C++ only, so I downloaded Eclipse, also, just in case.  In other words, I'm on Windows....  So the 'use ./config' mentioned in the Install file in the source code isn't translating meaning to me.

I did try reformatting my system and using Linux.  Unfortunately, even with some help from IRC, I couldn't figure out if I was compiling correctly.  If I was successful in any of my many attempts, I couldn't figure out how to start Gimp after I did 'compilation'.  So, I couldn't test my work at all.

Please advise.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin [project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/refocus/) seems to have been abandoned. The last version 0.9 dates from 2003, and [bug reports](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=72588&atid=535002) from 2004 and 2005 were never answered and are still open. You should be aware of the fact that versions numbered below 1.0 are beta versions.

You could try to get in touch with the developer of this plug-in, 
Ernst Lippe, at ernstl@users.sourceforge.net, but I do not think that you will get any answer.

Sorry to be negative, but I really think you should look for for another plugin that can do the job.

Comment: That's cool, Harry.  I appreciate the info and the digging you've done to answer.  There's still the issue of how to build a plugin into gimp, though.  I'm trying to figure out how to install various plugins into gimp from source to executable.

Comment: I guess this is because I am under the impression that, while some plugins can merely be dropped into the plugins folder, some plugins need to be compiled into the program.

Comment: I would counsel staying out of trouble and only using plugins that do not require compilation. Compilation is the mark of an outdated plugin that may not work without much fiddling in the latest GIMP version or the one after.

Comment: Looks like nobody's going to hook up the wiki post. :(  Oh well.  Thanks, harry.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install it and automate the install process. Please take a look at **install-refocus** script at [Automatic Broccoli](https://github.com/bit-man/automatic-broccoli).

**EDIT** (Thanks @davidpostill and @scott for the sugestions)

The basic idea was to download and extract the refocus code (located at SourceForge), download a [port of refocus for Gimp 2.x](http://page.sourceforge.net/refocus-0.9.0_gimp2_rozen.tgz) and extract over the previous folder, set the GIMPTOOL environment variable to the `gimptool-2.0` path, add the mathematical library to the list of libraries to be linked, run configure, correct the call to GIMPTOOL located at src/Makefile and finally run `make install-bin`. The script code follows :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Thanks Don Rozenberg for major changes to refocus 0.9.0 to make it compile for GIMP 2.x !!
## (http://www.gimpusers.com/mailmsg.php?42F58785.5090109%40mcn.org)

destFolder=/tmp

function download() {
  cd $2 && wget -O - $1 | tar xzf -
  local exitCode=$?
  cd -
  return $exitCode
}

function cleanup() {
  rm -rf ${refocusPath} ${refocusGimp2Path}
}

## Add -lm at the end to avoid floor@@GLIBC_2.2.5 compilation ERROR
## (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10274645/1085978 and https://github.com/xmlroff/xmlroff/issues/1)
export LIBS="-lm $LIBS"
export GIMPTOOL=${GIMPTOOL:-`which gimptool-2.0`}
refocusPath=${destFolder}/refocus-0.9.0
refocusGimp2Path=${destFolder}/refocus-0.9.0_gimp2_rozen


cleanup
download https://sourceforge.net/projects/refocus/files/latest/download ${destFolder} \
  && download  http://page.sourceforge.net/refocus-0.9.0_gimp2_rozen.tgz ${destFolder} \
  && cp -R ${refocusGimp2Path}/* ${refocusPath} \
  && cd ${refocusPath} && ./configure \
  && sed 's/@GIMPTOOL@ --install/${GIMPTOOL} --install/' -i src/Makefile \
  && make install-bin
cleanup
```

Comment: If you have an answer please post it, not just a link to it.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: [Debian](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/gimp-plugin-registry/-/tree/debian/7.20140602/refocus) and [arch](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/gimp-refocus) also had their own patching.